# Replace variable value in first file based on records in second in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have below files 
a) File A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root xmlns="http://aaa/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <project name="source">
        <mapping name="m_Source">
            <parameter name="SQL_Query">select  * from $$SCHEMA_NAME."$$TABLE_NAME" where $$COL > $$VALUE and $CONDITIONS</parameter>
            <parameter name="CONDITIONS">Default</parameter>
        </mapping>
    </project>
</root>
```

b) File b

```
$$SCHEMA_NAME=test
$$COL=LOAD_DATETIME
$$TABLE_NAME=table1
$$VALUE=1234
```

I want to replace the values of $$SCHEMA_NAME , $$COL , $$TABLE_NAME, $$VALUE with the values mentioned in right ( i.e. test,DATETIME,table1,1234) in file a

thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  a=$(echo $line | awk -F'=' '{print $1}')
  b=$(echo $line | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
  sed -i "s/$a/$b/" file_a
done < file_b
```

Brief explanation,

1. Read each line in file_b and assign the value which is left of equation to 'a', and right one to 'b'.
2. Use `sed` to substitute the value in 'a' to the value in 'b' in the file_a.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to redirect the output to a different file ?